# SQL Count and Sum Over Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
 ID         Date

62  2012-06-12 05:30:57.000
202 2012-06-13 00:00:00.000
73  2012-06-17 05:25:15.000
74  2012-06-17 06:20:00.000
75  2012-06-17 10:46:03.000
76  2012-06-17 11:15:33.000
77  2012-06-17 12:17:09.000
79  2012-06-17 21:12:44.000
81  2012-06-18 12:34:45.000
82  2012-06-18 16:46:29.000
83  2012-06-19 00:21:44.000
84  2012-06-20 11:31:52.000
86  2012-06-22 23:27:38.000
87  2012-06-23 17:02:18.000
89  2012-06-25 10:05:00.000
91  2012-06-25 12:36:13.000
92  2012-06-25 15:28:36.000
93  2012-06-26 12:16:45.000
97  2012-06-27 14:03:14.000
98  2012-06-27 14:20:37.000
99  2012-06-27 16:21:21.000
114 2012-06-28 21:58:43.000
115 2012-06-29 10:46:53.000
120 2012-07-09 01:11:34.000
```

This goes on for multiple years.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID) AS [Count], Q.Start_Date AS [Date]
FROM Questionaires as Q 
GROUP BY Q.Start_Date
```

I'm trying to sum each month's count.
For example if:

```
Date       Count    Total
2012-06     10       10
2012-07     5        15
```

Comment: What's the total column meant to be, is it a running total?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to get a running total for each month by year.

Comment: i updated my response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cast each [Date] to a date it removes the time, and if you deduct the day (minus one) we get the first day of the month. Then Group by that. Finally use SUM() OVER() to form the running total.

also: 
CONVERT(varchar(7), [Date], 120) produces a string of YYYY-MM, if you have MS SQL 2012+ you could use FORMAT([Date], 'yyyy-MM') instead.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73efb/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Questionaires 
    ([ID] int, [Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Questionaires 
    ([ID], [Date])
VALUES
    (62, '2012-06-12 05:30:57'),
    (202, '2012-06-13 00:00:00'),
    (73, '2012-06-17 05:25:15'),
    (74, '2012-06-17 06:20:00'),
    (75, '2012-06-17 10:46:03'),
    (76, '2012-06-17 11:15:33'),
    (77, '2012-06-17 12:17:09'),
    (79, '2012-06-17 21:12:44'),
    (81, '2012-06-18 12:34:45'),
    (82, '2012-06-18 16:46:29'),
    (83, '2012-06-19 00:21:44'),
    (84, '2012-06-20 11:31:52'),
    (86, '2012-06-22 23:27:38'),
    (87, '2012-06-23 17:02:18'),
    (89, '2012-06-25 10:05:00'),
    (91, '2012-06-25 12:36:13'),
    (92, '2012-06-25 15:28:36'),
    (93, '2012-06-26 12:16:45'),
    (97, '2012-06-27 14:03:14'),
    (98, '2012-06-27 14:20:37'),
    (99, '2012-06-27 16:21:21'),
    (114, '2012-06-28 21:58:43'),
    (115, '2012-06-29 10:46:53'),
    (120, '2012-07-09 01:11:34')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      CONVERT(varchar(7), [Date], 120) AS yr_month
    , CountOf
    , SUM(CountOf) OVER (order by [Date]) as Total
FROM (
      SELECT
            DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(Q.Date) - 1), CAST(Q.[Date] as Date)) AS [Date]
          , COUNT(*) AS [CountOf]
      FROM Questionaires AS Q
      GROUP BY
            DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(Q.Date) - 1), CAST(Q.[Date] as Date))
      ) AS d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73efb/1/0)**:

```
| yr_month | CountOf | Total |
|----------|---------|-------|
|  2012-06 |      23 |    23 |
|  2012-07 |       1 |    24 |
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
select str(year) + '-' + str(month) as month, total, count
from (
SELECT COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID) AS [Count], sum(Q.[Count]) as total, MONTH(Q.Start_Date) as month, YEAR(Q.Start_Date) as year
FROM Questionaires as Q 
GROUP BY MONTH(Q.Start_Date), YEAR(Q.Start_Date)
 ) pretty
```

something like this?

here it is in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d955/4

Comment: How are you generating the Count column?

Comment: Well you only gave us 2 columns, date and id - i made it up since i didnt have any other data, i dont know what you call it on your end. Look at the sqlfiddle link and play around with it. Its not magic :P

Comment: I can make it sum `Questionaire_ID ` .. i just figured your real data has more data.

Comment: It actually doesn't have any more data to key off of.

Comment: ok, change `COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID) AS [Count], sum(Q.[Count]) as total,` to `COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID) AS [Count], sum(Q.Questionaire_ID) as total,` then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92555/discussion-between-javier-buzzi-and-ckallemeres).

Answer (score 1):

By "cumulative sum", I assume you mean "count".  You need to extract the year and month and group by those columns as well:

```
SELECT YEAR(Q.Start_Date) as yyyy, MONTH(Q.Start_Date) as mm,
       COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID) AS [Count]
FROM Questionaires as Q 
GROUP BY YEAR(Q.Start_Date), MONTH(Q.Start_Date)
ORDER BY yyyy, mm;
```

EDIT:

If you want the cumulative count, then that is also easily done:

```
SELECT YEAR(Q.Start_Date) as yyyy, MONTH(Q.Start_Date) as mm,
       COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID) AS [Count],
       SUM(COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(Q.Start_Date), MONTH(Q.Start_Date)) as CumeCount
FROM Questionaires as Q 
GROUP BY YEAR(Q.Start_Date), MONTH(Q.Start_Date)
ORDER BY yyyy, mm;
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for the cumulative total of the count column.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the datetime field to date only:

```
SELECT COUNT(Q.Questionaire_ID) AS [Count], CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(Q.Start_Date AS VARCHAR(12)),103) AS [Date]
FROM Questionaires as Q 
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(Q.Start_Date AS VARCHAR(12)),103)
```

Here we are converting the datetime field to a VARCHAR but only taking the first 12 characters, which excludes the time.

Comment: I dont think `CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(Q.Start_Date AS VARCHAR(12)),103)` will work OP. It just makes `2012-06-12 05:30:57.000` -> `June, 12 2012 00:00:00` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e62e48/9

Comment: It will group by date and provide a count of records per date, if you dont convert and discard the time portion then it will provide an inaccurate count of records per hour:minute.

Comment: right, but you need to get rid of the 'day' too, the hour and seconds is not enough. OP wants grouping by month. not day/month/year.

Answer (score 0):

```
    i think this example is useful for you 

CREATE TABLE RunTotalTestData (
   id    int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
   value int not null
);

INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (12);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (13);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (16);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (22);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (42);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (57);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (58);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (59);
INSERT INTO RunTotalTestData (value) VALUES (60);


SELECT a.id, a.value, (SELECT SUM(b.value)
                       FROM RunTotalTestData b
                       WHERE b.id <= a.id)
FROM   RunTotalTestData a
ORDER BY a.id;


id   value   running total
--   -----   -------------
1    1       1
2    2       3
3    4       7
4    7       14
5    9       23
6    12      35
7    13      48
8    16      64
9    22      86
10   42      128
11   57      185
12   58      243
13   59      302
14   60      362
```